# Can we increase the Parallelism for Non-Keyed Windows by setParallelism?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From the article below we know the parallelism is 1 for non-keyed streams, so can we increase the parallelism by setParallelism ?
"In case of non-keyed streams, your original stream will not be split into multiple logical streams and all the windowing logic will be performed by a single task, i.e. with parallelism of 1."

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#keyed-vs-non-keyed-windows

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you would try to use [setParallelism](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/SingleOutputStreamOperator.html#setParallelism-int-) to set a different value than 1 on an operator of a stream within an All Window operator, an exception will be thrown. This functionality is also exposed, as you can use [forceNonParallel](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/SingleOutputStreamOperator.html#forceNonParallel--) to ensure that the parallelism of the corresponding operator cannot be overridden.

Comment: The  forceNonParallel[2]  means set the Parallelism to 2?  However  from the Api document desc "forceNonParallel would Sets the parallelism and maximum parallelism of this operator to one" and also it seems cannot be called with a Parallelism  parameter 2 or other number.